# TypeError: (0 , _axios.default) is not a function when use jest.mock('axios') inside a *.test.js file

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs, axios

I try to mock `axios` module inside my test file like this

```
// mycomponent.test.js
import axios from 'axios';

jest.mock('axios', () => ({
  get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: 'data' })),
  default: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: 'data' })),
}));
```

But after i add `jest.mock('axios')` into my test file, i got an error like this.

```
TypeError: (0 , _axios.default) is not a function

      55 |       this.props.updateGlobalLoading(true);
      56 | 
    > 57 |       axios({
         |       ^
      58 |         method: 'get',
      59 |         url: '/v1/api/portal-xml-list',
      60 |       }).then((res) => {
```

So how should i fix this, any thing that i missed to set for `axios` mocking?

Thanks!

Answer (score 31):

If you want to mock the default and named exports of a module (`axios` in this case), the property `__esModule` must be enabled in the return value:

```
jest.mock('axios', () => ({
    __esModule: true,
    get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: 'data' })),
    default: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: 'data' })),
}));
```

Alternatively, as it seems that you are only using the default export of `axios`, you could mock the default export as:

```
jest.mock('axios', () => jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: 'data' })));
```

Comment: Wow, that is fantastic. But I don't understand why using the requireActual from jest does not add that? `jest.mock('lib', () => ({ ...jest.requireActual('lib'), otherMEthods }))`

Comment: @mgarcia how do I mock a Promise.reject for axios.default in another test case ?

Comment: This helped me in mocking an axios call from an async mounted hook in vue. Thanks!! @mgarcia

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up to @mgarcia's answer, I kept getting the following error when using his/her version:

```
ReferenceError: The module factory of `jest.mock()` is not allowed to reference 
any out-of-scope variables.
Invalid variable access: jest
```

The error was caused by the `jest.fn()` method inside `jest.mock()`. So I just removed it like so and was able to mock `axios` successfully:

```
jest.mock('axios', () => ({
    get: () => Promise.resolve({ data: 'data' }),
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with `as unknown as jest.Mock`

```
// package.json
"axios": "^1.3.4",
"jest": "^29.5.0",
"jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.5.0",
```

```js
jest.mock('axios', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: jest.fn(),
}));

beforeEach(() => {
  (axios as unknown as jest.Mock).mockReset();
});
```